# Launching a command in terminal from the app launcher

Tags: pantheon-terminal, release-juno

I would like to launch this simple oneliner in terminal, but from app launcher.

```
curl wttr.in/bydgoszcz
```

It just shows nice weather report, like this:
[image]

I found out that it is possible to launch a terminal from the script and make it launch a command, with:

```
#!/bin/sh
exec io.elementary.terminal -e "curl wttr.in/bydgoszcz"
```

But this way the output gest strangely corrupted (notice where the `user@machine` line lands):
[image]

Its just like if the weather report command gets executed too fast. Is there a way to maybe delay it somehow, so the `user@machine` line goes first, and then goes the report, just like in the #1 image

Answer (score 2):

I've tried writing a script, changing the output, etc but the problem is (I believe) on elementary's terminal not waiting the command to end

Because I've changed the command using cat instead of curl (to test that thought), having curl output the website to a temp text, and got the same result with the command prompt

Also haven't tried another terminal to compare results

---

The solution I see could fit as a probable solution, is to write code in C, Python or w/e language you want...compile it and run it.

---

### UPDATE

I've made my first `Vala` app just for this :P , I modified an example code with my knowledge of other languages and worked

https://github.com/rscm/wttr/blob/master/wttr

Just download the file and it will load the default url wttr.in in a webview. If you call the file with and argument like `bydgoszcz` will load that location. I didn't validate any input so don't send weird stuff

Summary:

- `./wttr` is the same as `curl wttr.in`
- `./wttr bydgoszcz` is the same as `curl wttr.in/bydgoszcz`

Tomorrow I'll upload the code in the repo if you want to modify it

Comment: Thanks for it. It's definately a nicer workaround than Maccer's.
Pls upload the code for modification.

Comment: Uploaded, have fun with it :P

Answer (score 0):

This is not the answer you were looking for but... Why do all of this when you can install a web app and click a icon on the Applications launcher?

Just open Epiphany and go to [wttr.in/bydgoszcz](http://wttr.in/bydgoszcz). Then press the gear button and select "Install Site as Web Application".
[image]

Now the app is available with just a click from the launcher!

Comment: Thats a nice trick, but the goal is to launch it in terminal, it looks way nicer this way, slicker.